# Using loop in csv file create separate file for each line

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed, csv-simple

I have a csv file containing

```
a,b,c  
d,e,f   
g,h,i
```

now using this I want to create 3 separate files `a.txt`, `d.txt`, `g.txt` (named after the first field) for each record of that csv.

Each file will contain a single command line.

- `a.txt` should contain:

  ```
  cat b|grep c
  ```
- `d.txt` should contain:

  ```
  cat e|grep f
  ```
- `g.txt` should contain:

  ```
  cat h|grep i
  ```

I am able to loop them but I am not able to add this in the file.

Comment: Why are you using `cat` to con`cat`enating a single file? Wouldn't it make more sense to write it `grep c b` or `<b grep c`?

Comment: Please update your question to explicitly show what the files should look like given your example data.

Comment: the file should contain the 1 liner command , if we look in file a.txt it should contain line cat b|grep c  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` and assuming you want to write code in the `sh` language and that is simple csv without quoted fields, fields with embedded commas or newlines:

```
LC_ALL=C awk -F, -v q="'" '
  function shquote(s) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
    return q s q
  }
  {
    file = $1".txt"
    print "grep -e "shquote($3)" < "shquote($2) > file
    close(file)
  }' < file.csv
```

Instead of `cat b | grep c`, that's doing `grep -e 'c' < 'b'` as:

1. It doesn't make sense to concatenate a *single* file. Here, you can make `grep`'s stdin the file directly hence the redirection instead of piping the output of `cat`.
2. Strings are quoted to avoid problems with characters that are special in the shell's syntax.
3. Using `grep -e regexp` instead of `grep regexp` to avoid problems with regexps starting with `-`.

Comment: Thanks Stephane !!! this really worked. You saved my weeks effort. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "," '{print "touch "$1".txt"";""echo cat "$2"|grep "$3"> "$1".txt"}' CSVfilename| sed 's/cat/"&/g'| sed 's/>/"&/g'|sh
```

Tested and worked fine